# How do I change my Trigger.IO iOS application name from `Forge`?

Tags: trigger.io

When i view my built iOS Trigger.IO application in the iPhone Configuration Utility tool it has a name `Forge`. How do I change this to my own name ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, the `Forge` name is baked in: is there a reason we've overlooked for why customising the binary name is required?

Comment: Yes - installing two different apps packaged with Trigger.IO and trying to manage them in the iPhone Configuration Utility. You cant tell them appart because they have the same name (Forge). I would really like to be able to customise this please.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the value in your config.json like this:

```
    "config_version": "3", 
    "uuid": "xxx", 
    "author": "joe.blow@whatever.com",
    "name": "My App", 
    "platform_version": "v1.4", 
    "version": "1.0.0", 
    "description": "Your app description."
```

Alternatively you can utilize the Toolkit UI -  http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/config.html

Comment: Kris, this doesn't answer the question. There seems to be an internal name `Forge` for my iOS app that is only viewable in the iPhone Configuration utility. Its not the application name that the user sees, nor the `package_names.ios` value. Its something else that doesnt appear to be configurable.